# $resource : $save does not work

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json file called **data.json** containing some data:

```
[
    {
        "name"      : "toto"
    }
]
```

And the script I wrote to manage it :

```
var Data = $resource("data.json", {}, 
    {
        query: {method:'GET',isArray:true}
    });  

    var data = Data.query(function()
    {
        var d = data[0];        
        d.name = "Titi";
        d.$save();  
    });
```

Everything work before I call **$save()** on my object. I have this error:

```
     [11:30:24.962] "Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. 
Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

I don't really know the problem. I have already read many examples and documentations but this does not seem clearer to me.

Comment: The response of $save seems to be an array. Can you check what response server sends on save?

Comment: How can I do that ? 
Otherwise, I tried to put `save : {isArray:true}` in the resources actions. But now, angular tells me that **push** of the value object is not a function ... which is obviously not the case because is try to save a single object ... I don't really get it ...

Comment: For save the ideal response should be a single object? Therefore can you see your browser debug console network tab and see what is the response for save, it should not be an array.

Comment: Well, `Data.save()` works, but does nothing (no data saved).
And the request response using `d.$save()` is an array, with no modification (**name** is "toto", and not "Titi").

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing to help quickly here... You may have several issues, var d = data[0]. data should be from an argument/parameter of the function not the var data which is null until the return result from Data.query changes it.  $save should also likely be on the $resource object, not the object in the array.  Not an angular person, but guessing that might be the case.

Comment: As the callback function of query() is called after data was loaded  from the server, I think that my var **data** is populated when I use it in the function. Also, the method **$save** is only for the resources instances, not for the resources themselves (which save function is just **save**). Anyway, I have just tried both of your advices, but there is always the same error.